Configuration issue with ssh remote tunneling
As a school teacher, I intend to use my own Moodle server installed
locally on a computer of the school.
For now, this website is only accessible locally at http://172.19.130.191:80
I would like to make this website accessible from outside the
school's network. I used ngrok, https://ngrok.com/, although there are
some instability issues and the url is not that easy to remember
for students. So I thought of using ssh (remote) tunneling.
Here is the context:

at home, a raspberry pi 4 with ssh server accessible from the internet
at rpi4@home.hopto.org (fake address) on port 22. This rpi4 is connected to a network
extender TP link Deco. My local network (from the box of my ISP) is
is 192.168.1.0/24 and the local network from Deco X50 is 192.168.68.0/24.
(of course I made port forwarding 22 on the ISP's box and the Deco X50 so that the rpi4 is publicly
accessible).

at work, the server on which Moodle is installed is behind a strict
firewall. I bind a DNS to the public address of this computer using
the noip service (https://www.noip.com/) and let's call this DNS
school.hopto.org but it seems there is no use doing it because
I cannot even ping this DNS (due to the firewall).
In short, I cannot installed a ssh server on this computer because
it would not be accessible publicly (it seems the 22 port is blocked) so
I cannot employ ssh local tunneling. Here is for instance the output
of the command:
➜  ~ nmap -Pn school.hopto.org
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-07-10 07:58 CEST
Nmap scan report for school.hopto.org (193.54.246.80)
Host is up (0.00092s latency).
rDNS record for x.x.x.x: xx.xx.ch
Not shown: 999 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
113/tcp closed ident
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.26 seconds


That's why I would like to use ssh remote tunneling where my rpi4 would be intermediary node of the traffic.
Here is the command I use on the school's computer:
➜  ~ ssh -vvv -nNT -p 2222 -R \*:2222:localhost:80 rpi4@home.hopto.org


OpenSSH_9.6p1, OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host home.hopto.org originally home.hopto.org
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host home.hopto.org originally home.hopto.org
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/lucie/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/lucie/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "home.hopto.org" port 2222
debug3: resolve_host: lookup home.hopto.org:2222
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to home.hopto.org [x.x.x.x] port 2222.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 2222: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host home.hopto.org port 2222: Connection timed out


Also, for debugging purpose, let's see if I can open a ssh session to the rpi with a remote port forwarding. I enter on the school computer:
ssh -R \*:2222:localhost:22 rpi4@home.hopto.org

then the rpi4 is listening on 2222:
rpi4@rpi4:~ $ netstat -ano | grep 2222
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)

but I cannot open a ssh session on port 2222 on the rpi4:
rpi4@rpi4:~ $ ssh -p 2222 rpi4@localhost
rpi4@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

and this last output message should be related to the ssh server configuration.
Here is the configuration of my ssh server on the rpi4:
Port 22
MaxAuthTries 6
MaxSessions 7

PasswordAuthentication yes

KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

UsePAM yes

AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
PermitTunnel yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

I do not know the cause of this problem: is it due to bad configuration (could the Deco X50 be a problem, I do not configure it except the port 22 that is redirected to the rpi4)? or because the school's computer doesn't allow it? In the latter case, is there a way to verify it? Does the ssh remote tunneling always working or the administrator can prevent it?

(1) "of course I made port forwarding 22 on the ISP's box and the Deco X50 so that the rpi4 is publicly accessible" – This is why ssh -p 2222 … failed and ssh …  on the default port succeeded. (2) "but I cannot open a ssh session on port 2222 on the rpi4" – You first tried to use -R \*:2222:localhost:80, but finally you have -R \*:2222:localhost:22. The question seems to be about a tunnel to a HTTP server, then it turns out you want(?) a tunnel to the SSH server of the school computer. This is somewhat confusing.

(1). Ok I also forwarded the port 2222 of my ISP's box to the port 2222 of the DecoX50. I am still the same error message :
rpi4@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
(2) yes not clear, I edited it. The final part of the question is for debugging only and is not related to what I want to do.

Just an aside: it's rarely a good idea to create a shadow-IT environment on a corporate network. If your moodle server actually becomes reachable and subsequently exploited all hell will break loose, and rightfully so. There are reasons for firewalling ...
